# How do I record and/or create a vim macro that includes the character 'q' in normal mode?

Tags: vim, macros

It is well-known that `q` is used to begin recording and also to terminate recording a macro.

Unfortunately, I am trying to record a sequence of commands which includes the command `q:`, and the macro (naturally) stops recording at `q`.

Is there a way I can record a sequence of commands that includes `q` typed in normal mode?

Update: I have tried remapping `q` to something else and mapping another letter to `q`, but this seems to break the functionality of `q` for the actual command I am trying to record.

Comment: are you sure the command contains `q:` and not `:q`?

Comment: Yes. `q:` opens a command buffer where you can edit lines in your command history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `:`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to open the command history window without stopping the recording.

Comment: In general, how do you find these "alternative" commands? That is, for given function `x` how do I find all `y` such that `y` does the equivalent of `x` without using letter `z`?

Answer (score 3):

well you have got the accepted answer, I just mention another trick to record macro, so that you can have `q:` in macro:

You could press `:ctrl-f`, or if you really love `q:`, you could:

for example:

```
let @q='5j5kq:<c-v><up><c-v><enter>j'
```

`5j5k` does nothing, just for example.

`200@q` will for next 200lines execute the last command. If your last command pass some arguments like current line number or current line (text) to a function. it will work too.

If you want to edit the command line in macro, you need before the `<c-v><enter>` press the key-sequence.

for `<c-v><up><c-v><enter>`, you need really type like that, not plain text.

but from my point of view, those tricks are not needed for common tasks.

Comment: +1, this trick is definitely useful too, although in for this particular problem perreal's solution is faster for me.